# Add word vectors as columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, gensim, word2vec

I have a dataframe with column `keywords`:

```
keywords
election
countries
majestic
dollar
....
....
...
```

I also have my own pretrained word2vec model using gensim from where I can get 20 dimension vectors for each word using `model['anyword']`. My question is

i) I want to assign these 20 dimension vectors as columns names (V1 to V20) corresponding to each keyword.

ii) if word is not present in word vocabulary then i want to assign the vectors as array of [0,0,0,,,,,0] corresponding to that word otherwise it will give an `error:word not present in vocabulary`. for example if word `majestic` is not present in vocab then `df` would should like

```
keyword     V1     V2      V3 ............. V20
election   0.02    0.44    0.32.............0.12
countries  0.33    0.33    0.11............ 0.13
majestic   0       0       0   ............ 0
dollar     0.31    0.77    0.86............ 0.91
.......
.......
```

as far what I have done so far:-

```
for i in df['keywords']:
    vectors=model['i']
```

I got array of vector but Im not getting how put it with columns names as `V1 V2 V3 V4....V20` in `df` and how to treat missing word as `'0'`

Comment: Is this the proper way one would, say, take the embedding from GloVe or word2vec, and use them to train a deep learning model? Is this the proper way to represent those embedding in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like the below given code.
First make the function like this.For the word not in vocabulary I have used try-except so that if the word is not in vocabulary it will place the list of 0 there.

```
missing=[0]*20
def fun(key):
    try:
        return(model[key])
    except:
        return(missing)
```

Then call this function:

```
df['vector'] = df['keywords'].apply(fun)
df = pd.DataFrame(df['vector'].values.tolist())
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @James are you still facing any problem??

Comment: is it any other way as might be columns names got increased i.e it could be 500

Comment: I have edited the answer. Have a look at it. If you face further any problem comment it.